# safari ios audio- refusing to play with error

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, safari

The javascript error is: `Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.`

My setup works across other browsers, desktop and mobile.

The way it works is:

- have a flag `first_audio_played = false;`
- add a touch event listener that plays some audio, and sets `first_audio_played = true;` (then removes the touch listener)
- all subsequent audio checks `if(first_audio_played) some_other_audio.play();`

this way, only the *first* audio played requires direct user input. after that, all audio is free to be triggered by in-game events, timing, etc...

this appears to be the "rule" for audio across most browsers. is the iOS "rule" that *every* audio needs to be triggered by user input? or is there some other step I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

For my javascript game, sounds stopped working on iOS recently. They all have readyState=4, but only the sound I played on tap works, the others won't play. Maybe you could play all the sounds on the first tap. But the solution I found that works for now for me is to load all the sounds from ajax arraybuffers and use decodeAudioData(). Then once you've played 1 sound from user tap (on not the body), they all play whenever.

Here is my working code where the second way of doing it is on bottom. When I tap to play sound2, sound1 starts working also.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id=all style='font-size:160%;background:#DDD' onclick="log('clicked');playSound(myAudio)">
            Sound1 should be playing every couple seconds.
            <br />Tap here to play sound1.
        </div>
        <div id=debug style='font-size:120%;' onclick="playSound(myAudio2)">
            Tap here to play the sound2.
        </div>
        <script>
            var url = "http://curtastic.com/drum.wav"
            var url2 = "http://curtastic.com/gold.wav"
            var myAudio, myAudio2
            if(0)
            {
                var playSound = function(sound)
                {
                    log("playSound() readyState="+sound.readyState)
                    log("gold readyState="+myAudio2.readyState)
                    sound.play()
                }

                var loadSound = function(url, callback)
                {
                    var audio = new Audio(url)
                    audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function()
                    {
                        log('canplaythrough');
                        if(callback)
                            callback()
                    }, false)

                    audio.load()
                    if(audio.readyState > 3)
                    {
                        log('audio.readyState > 3');
                        if(callback)
                            callback()
                    }
                    return audio
                }

                myAudio = loadSound(url, startInterval)
                myAudio2 = loadSound(url2)
            }
            else
            {
                var playSound = function(sound)
                {
                    log("playSound()")
                    var source = audioContext.createBufferSource()
                    if(source)
                    {
                        source.buffer = sound
                        if(!source.start)
                            source.start = source.noteOn

                        if(source.start)
                        {
                            var gain = audioContext.createGain()
                            source.connect(gain)
                            gain.connect(audioContext.destination)

                            source.start()
                        }
                    }
                }

                var loadSound = function(url, callback)
                {
                    log("start loading sound "+url)

                    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest()
                    ajax.open("GET", url, true)
                    ajax.responseType = "arraybuffer"
                    ajax.onload = function()
                    {
                        audioContext.decodeAudioData(
                            ajax.response,
                            function(buffer)
                            {
                                log("loaded sound "+url)
                                log(buffer)
                                callback(buffer)
                            },
                            function(error)
                            {
                                log(error)
                            }
                        )

                    }
                    ajax.send()
                }

                var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext
                var audioContext = new AudioContext()

                loadSound(url, function(r) {myAudio = r; startInterval()})
                loadSound(url2, function(r) {myAudio2 = r})
            }

            function startInterval()
            {
                log("startInterval()")
                setInterval(function()
                {
                    playSound(myAudio)
                }, 2000)
            }

            function log(m)
            {
                console.log(m)
                debug.innerHTML += m+"<br />"
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `[WKWebViewConfiguration setMediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback:WKAudiovisualMediaTypeNone]` or `[UIWebView setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO]` depending on your *WebView* class (or Swift equivalent).